# Why Error("trailing characters") when trying to deserialize a JSON file to a hashmap?

Tags: serialization, rust, deserialization, serde

So basically, I'm trying to deserialize a JSON file into a hashmap<String,String> using the serde crate, but. The JSON file:

```
"
    [
        {
            "orchard_name": "Happy Apple",
            "tons": "5"
        },
        {
            "orchard_name": "Munch for Lunch",
            "tons": "2"
        }
    ]
    "
```

This is my structure:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct OrangeFarm
{
    map : HashMap<String,String>
}
```

and this is where I try to do the deserialization:

```
let res = serde_json::from_str(_json);
if res.is_ok() {println!("Deserealization worked."); }
else { println!("it went wrong"); }
let mut deserializedFarm : OrangeFarm = res.unwrap();
```

For some reason, it works if I delete the second {}, but it doesn't if I let the second {} as I get this error "thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error("trailing characters" . Do you have any idea why this happens? Thank you!

Comment: Does your JSON file actually contain the pair of quotes surrounding everything?

Comment: Does the json file really contain the very first and very last quote? Furthermore, your JSON seems to be an array of objects, yet you try to deserialize it into a struct containing a HashMap

Comment: They do have the very first and last quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For some reason, it works if I delete the second {}, but it doesn't if I let the second {}

I have no idea what this means, but as far as I can see it never works: you're trying to deserialise an array of structures but you're deserialising to a structure. So the deserialisation logically fails. The code always panics, though in the initial case it *also* prints "it went wrong".

Furthermore, your structure definition doesn't match the JSON so even if you try deserializing to a `Vec<OrangeFarm>` the call will fail: `serde` expects to find a `map` attribute, which is not present in the JSON. So you need to either fix your structure, or configure the serialisation / deserialisation scheme.

Deserializing to a `Vec<HashMap<String, String>>` would work but I've no idea whether that is your intent.

That aside:

- Please provide [minimal complete runnable reproduction cases](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=db47289f6dfd653f6d99805d2907ac46) using play.rust-lang.org when that is possible (which it is here) and use regular code blocks to show the case in the comment, these html snippet things obviously can't work for rust (especially when the code is not even complete) so they just take room and break syntax coloration
- What little code there is is... odd. One would not normally check for `is_ok`/`is_err` then immediately unwrap, instead you'd use `match` or `if let` to cleanly do both at the same time and avoid the risk of desync, misunderstanding, etc... there are situations where `unwrap`.
- Calling a variable you're actively using `_json` is abnormal, the `_` prefix is intended for variables you want to capture but don't want to use (it suppresses the `unused_variables` lint without dropping the value immediately, which would be the effect of a lone `_`).

Comment: Ok, sorry. I'm new to Stackoverflow. So what type of data should I best choose to deserialize my JSON file? I thought I could deserialize the JSON somehow into a HashMap directly, but it wouldn't work.

Comment: I need to somehow make the sum of the tons. So I think your method with Vec won't work. I thought about creating a struct with two Vec<String> but it won't work cuz that's a sequence and the JSON is a map.

Comment: The json is an array of maps, so deserialising to a vector of maps is by far the most straightforward and works fine. If you need to sum the values you'll need to convert them fsrom strings to integers explicitely anyway. Or you can deserialize to a `Vec<OrchardInfo>` where `struct OrchardInfo { orchard_name: String, tons: String }` in order to avoid the overhead of hashmaps. Using [serde_with](https://docs.rs/serde_with) and the correct annotation it should even be possible to have `tons: usize` or `tons:u32` to avoid the explicit deserialisation step.

Comment: I thought about deserializing to a Vec<Obj> where Obj is a struct with 2 strings. I mean that's what I can understand from the JSON file. It is an array of objects. So why shouldn't that work? @Masklinn We posted at the same time. So exactly how I thought about it. Thank you sir! I'll give it a try